# Scaling graph along x axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, scaling

I am trying to plot a symple graph with `pgfplots` but the numbers do not seem to appear right. Is it possible to somehow scale the left part of the graph? I would also like the numbers on the x axis not to appear as scientific notation.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}  
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ %
bar width=9pt,
nodes near coords,
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,use comma},
scaled ticks=false,
width=1.0\textwidth,
%height=1.0\textheight,
xlabel={Ano},
ylabel={População},
xmin=0, ymin=0,
xmax=350,
ytick=data, xtick=data,
]
\addplot coordinates {
(40,1000)
(50,1400)
(100,7530)
(150,40496)
(200,217795)
(250,1171356)
(300,6299832)
(350,33882008)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Maybe it would be better to plot a progression starting with 1000 at year 40 -- I just want to *visualize* a 40% increase per decade between years 40 and 350. How can I do that?

Comment: Joseph, when you say "per decade" you really mean include nodes to show changes every 10 years? It would be helpful if you could include something to show what would you like the result to be (as a mockup).

Comment: I don't need nodes every 10 years -- I guess the coordinates I input are enough as nodes. If I could just input the function starting in year 40 and ending in year 350, I didn't even need those coordinates, which are actually from a table.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ytick=data` `pgfplots` puts a tick for each coordinate you insert so your first coordinate overlaps.. in my opinion the better way of showing such data is to use a semilog axis environment in this way:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}  
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[ %
bar width=9pt,
nodes near coords,
%y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,use comma,scaled y ticks=false},
scaled ticks=false,
width=1.0\textwidth,
%height=1.0\textheight,
xlabel={Ano},
ylabel={População},
xmin=0, ymin=0,
xmax=350,
%ytick=data
xtick=data,
]
\addplot coordinates {
(40,1000)
(50,1400)
(100,7530)
(150,40496)
(200,217795)
(250,1171356)
(300,6299832)
(350,33882008)
};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it looks great, even the progression is clearly shown, except that I don't know what the numbers along the line mean. Maybe it would be better to plot a progression starting with 1000 at year 40 -- I just want to _visualize_ a 40% increase per decade between years 40 and 350. I will edit the question to fit that purpose.